# Get component name in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a React application. I have a Loading component, which is a little animation for waiting. I want to add a message in this Loading component according to the component which called it.

Here is how i call my Loading component (with this.state.displayLoading at true or false) :

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    render() {   
        return (
            <div className="login-form-root">
                 {this.state.displayLoading && <Loading loadingFrom={?}/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to get "LoginForm" in my variable loadingFrom, which is the className. Maybe it's not the right way to do that.

Comment: `<Loading loadingFrom="LoginForm"/>`

Comment: So your login form manages its own loading state? Depending which technology you use behind the scenes this can generate some problems

Comment: I would prefer to have a this.component.name or something like that, is it possible ?

Comment: Sure that's possible (with some extra work) however, since you add it to the component itself (in your example) there is no reason why you should make your code more complex than necessary

Comment: @Icepickle, yes, during our requests to our JEE API that can take few seconds, we prefer to just display a screen instead of waiting on the login page.

Comment: Do not forget about minification. Function names might be changed by minifier.

Comment: Ok, i understand, thank you !

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You don't need it to be dynamic since you are writing the component yourself and can pass it as a string

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    render() {   
        return (
            <div className="login-form-root">
                 {this.state.displayLoading && <Loading loadingFrom="LoginForm "/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However if you still need to access the name of the component, you could define the `displayName` property on the component

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
   static displayName = 'LoginForm';
    render() {   
        return (
            <div className="login-form-root">
                 {this.state.displayLoading && <Loading loadingFrom="LoginForm "/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and access it like `Component.displayName`.

Comment: Component.displayName is `undefined` for me. Hence I use Component.name. Seams to give me what I want.

Answer (score 65):

##### Class Components

You can use `this.constructor.name` to obtain the name of your component.

(Using React 16.x as of this writing)

Caveat: This won't work if you're minifying for production with Webpack.

##### Functional Components

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname

Comment: i just want to get the name of component in a method of it like `componentDidMount` , how to do it ??

Comment: Why won't this work with Webpack?  Could a work-around be to assign `this.constructor.name` to another variable?

Comment: My env is react_rails + webpack, it works for me in dev env at least.

Comment: It can work with webpack, you just have to set `keep_fnames` and `keep_classnames` to `true` in your production config's `uglify` options: https://github.com/LemonPi/issues_webpack_classname

Comment: How can this be used for function Components?

Comment: This is very outdated, not correct for function components

Comment: @Andy Yes, most likely since I wrote this answer 3 years ago. I am happy to update it. How did the API change?

Comment: well, React now allows function components, which aren't classes, hence have no `this.constructor.name`.  However, it seems from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname) that `displayName` is an official property of the `React.Component` class, and I believe `displayName` gets set automatically on function components as well.

Comment: @Andy You rock. Updated answer! 

Comment: So this is interesting.  A teammate of mine was calling `.name` on a functional component and it was working in our dev environment, but after building and pushing to a staging environment it was no longer working.  We never explicitly set the `name` so it does exist on functional components.  React 17.0.2 fwiw

Comment: @Mark When you built and pushed to staging, was it a development or production build?

Comment: Production build.  I was just pointing out that `.name` does work with functional components still, but not when you minify your code for production.

Comment: @Mark Right. That's what I expected you to say. :) Unfortunately the component names get minified, so I believe that's why `.name` does not work with `NODE_ENV='production'`.

Comment: It would appear that this is undefined in a functional component (with strict mode) or that it refers to the global this (without strict mode). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974257/463012)

Answer (score 32):

Every `React.Component` has a property called [`displayName`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#displayname) that JSX sets automatically, so theoretically you can use that property

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    render() {   
        return (
            <div className="login-form-root">
                {this.state.displayLoading && <Loading loadingFrom={this.displayName}/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** *(after multiple comments saying its not working)*

As per convention, react offers a code snippet to wrap getting the component name on their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging) which is the following:

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent) {
  class WithSubscription extends React.Component {/* ... */}
  WithSubscription.displayName = `WithSubscription(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
  return WithSubscription;
}

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';
}
```

As can be seen, they first check the display name, then the component name, and if all fails, then it will be just `'Component'`

Comment: React uses this for debug, as mentioned in the linked page, it is actually part of the JSX framework

Comment: I get `undefined` for that property.

Comment: @MrColes I just checked the react page I linked to, and it hasn't been removed, are you using it on a class component, or on a functional component?

Comment: @MrColes Me too I think it's only supposed to be used within JSX are you trying to use it inside something like `componentDidMount`?  In any case I'm going with `this.constructor.name` in that case, but don't understand the webpack issue.  This is just another piece of the gigantic mess that constitutes React, I wouldn't even be bothering with it if it weren't all the rage.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I updated with some more information I found on the documentation site, I personally think React is a huge adaptation, but once you are used to it, it's fun to use, and to make quick prototyping, but similarily good for more complex programs, though some more "have-tos or best practises" could be in place, but this is anyhow a fairly new language

Comment: @MrColes I updated the post with some more info found on the documentation website, please note that even React doesn't really use one standard way, but I added the code with reference to the site itself for more information

Comment: @Icepickle appreciate your efforts but React is not a *language*.  It is so different from other Javascript frameworks with their built-in *two* way binding.  And setState being asynchronous?  Ugh.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty true, framework would be a better description from my side  I thought wtf aswell when first working with it but after working a while longer with it, I do like it

Answer (score 2):

For HOCs: you can use `WrappedComponent.name`

Answer (score 2):

To make it work after webpack build you can assign a property to the function

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div />
  );
}
MyComponent.componentName = 'MyComponent';

function ParentComponent({ children }) {
  console.log("Children name", children.type.componentName);
}
```

Comment: This was my right answer. Everyone talking about class components, how about functional components. Getting the 'children name' works in development mode, but not after build, Doing it the way it's done in this answer makes `.componentName` accessible in the `type` object in production mode.

Like so `children.type.componentName`

Answer (score 0):

After searching with debugger, in newer versions you should use `this._reactInternalFiber.elementType.name` instead of `this._reactInternalInstance.getName()`

Comment: I don't think it's safe to use any framework variable that starts with underscore or has 'internal' in it.

Comment: Indeed. Why? Because it's liable to change without you knowing it (you're not supposed to use it, so why would they warn you).