# How i can show React component props value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the show `Input` component `name` props value.
I mean component props name, not component name.

```
 <Input
    type="radio"
    id="radio-input-1"
    name="radio-inupt"
    value="Mango"
 />
 <span>Input componet name is {Input.name}</span>
```

Comment: `<Input name="foo" />.props.name === 'foo' // true`

Comment: I don't understand how?

Comment: @SterlingArcher: That's a different question. Component name != name *prop*.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, rlemon explained it to me too. Retracted my vote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get component name in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react)

Answer (score -1):

> How i can show React component props value?

[**Components**](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) don't have prop values. A component is like a constructor, prop values are like arguments passed to the constructor. Since you can have a multiple "instances" of a component, the component itself cannot be associated with a specific set of prop values.

Instead, when you use `<Input ... />` you are actually calling [`React.createElement(Input, ...)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement). This returns an [**element**](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) (an "instance" of the component) and it's the element that is associated with the concrete prop values.

The shape of an element is not officially documented (at least not on the website), so accessing it is likely not something you should do, but if you really want to you can access the `props` property of the element:

```js
function Input() {}

var input = <Input
  type="radio"
  id="radio-input-1"
  name="radio-inupt"
  value="Mango"
/>;

console.log(`Input element name is ${input.props.name}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```