# Get name of react component onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to try and get the name of the react component that was clicked.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
   console.log("I WANTED TO PRINT 'MyComponent' HERE")
}

render() {
   <MyComponent onClick={this.handleClick}>
}
```

I could do this through using an added prop like `data-` or `name=` but I was wondering if there was a way to get `MyComponent` without having to type it multiple times.

The reason I want to do this is that I can get the name of the component so that I can change the CSS so that it is highlighted.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: It's probably doable, but there's a good reason why you shouldn't be doing this sort of thing. Why should the component know it's own name? What are you actually trying to accomplish? See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Maybe you can pass it along from based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react/43800947#43800947) however it's unsure to have a name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get component name in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react)

Comment: @ggorlen its so that I can get the name of the component so I can change the CSS to make it highlighted after the user clicks on it

Comment: In addition to being a duplicate, thikn about what you're trying to do: you're trying to get a component _of which you already know the class_ to get its class logged when it's clicked. Why not just put that information in the function call that should happen on click? `<MyComponent  onClick={ () => this.logClass(MyComponent ) }/>` and have `logClass(componentClass) { ... }` do what it needs to do.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans its a simplified example

Comment: And yet that approach still holds for more complex examples. Worth expanding your post if the duplicate suggestion doesn't cover what you need.

Comment: I'm at my vote limit, but I wish I could +10 Mike. There's almost never any reason for a code to be programmatically making decisions based on how you named stuff in the program. Use a click handler with a callback if you want to change CSS on a component. Seems like a pretty classic example of the x-y problem to me--when posting, state what you're trying to accomplish rather than how you might think the best way to accomplish it is.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll tell you the answer. Even though this is a duplicate, I'll tell you what the answer is.

## Short answer

**Yes...... but complicated.**

## Long answer

Let's start with this simple class:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(){
  console.log("Component");
}
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Component onClick={this.handleClick} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then what? First you want the component to be in the `handleClick()` function. That's as simple as this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name: "Component"
  }
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(){
  // or whatever you want to do with it, just replace "Component" with this.state.name
  console.log(this.state.name);
}
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Component onClick={this.handleClick} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

So what I did was add a new `this.state.name` and then use it in the `handleClick()` function. This is a good reason for the `bind(this)` line. So after `bind(this)`, the function would be able to access `state` directly. If you want to change `this.state.name`, then use `this.setState({name: /* whatever you want it to change to */ })`.

This is a little bit more efficent than the answer pointed out in the comments because for the answer pointed out in the comments, if you have multiple `<Component />`s, then you'll have to use "Component" more than 2 times. Instead, with this solution, you'll still only have to use "Component" only 2 times.

But there is still *almost* no way to use "Component" only 1 time. Why? Because both answers and a lot more have 2 references or more to "Component" because there is no way to directly connect tag names in the inside of the `return` directly to the outside of the class. What you might want, `<{this.state.name} />` does not exist. There are some ways to do this but they are still complicated.