# How to get name of the current component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

For example i am having a component like this,

```
import React from "react";

export default const App = () => {

    console.log("ComponrntName i.e App in this scenario")
    return (
   <div>
     <p>Hello World</p>
   </div>
)
}
```

how to get component name . (i.e) **App** in this scenario . Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the name'? Do you want to import in another file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get component name in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react)

Comment: Nope . that example is for class compont. Here i need for functional component

Answer (score 1):

You can set the displayName to a functional component like `App.displayName = "AppComponent";`

and inside the function you can access it with `App.displayName`

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {

    console.log("ComponrntName:", App.displayName);
    return (
        <div>
           <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    )

}
App.displayName = "AppComponent";
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }
}

this.constructor.name
```

you will get the Component