# What is the best way to get the name of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have been struggling about finding a method to get the name of a React component. I tried the `this.constructor.name` property. However learnt that it doesn't work in production mode since Webpack minifies the code. Is there any way I can use without any caveats?

Comment: Why do you need the component name?

Comment: Have you tried the wrapper code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43800947/8674094) yet?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react) answer your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to create an event emitter for react from child to parent. I put the methods in a map. And using component names as keys.@jason_r To be honest this solution seems so cumbersome for me. But I will give it a chance anyway.

Comment: You don't need to use component names, use id's as props instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's up on from where you need the name. If you can treat the component as a function (with hooks) you could just call `Function.name`

```js
function MyComponent({giveNameToParent}){
  
  const sendInfo(){
    giveNameToParent(MyComponent.name);
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div onClick={sendInfo}>Hi there!</div>
  );
 
}
```

I don't know if this can solve your problem, but if you need something more solid, please give more context to your case.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: After a little bit thinking I see that I don't need getting component name dynamically. So I literally write the name as a string. And that worked.