# Binding (this) to a function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to call a function onclick that uses the element being clicked. I plan on using `this.closest('selector')` later but for now I want to get the `this` working at all.
Here is the extent of the code that I think is relevant:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function App() {
  function printThis() {
    console.log(this);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       {Categories.map(Category => (
         <div className='get'>Get this from this.closest('.get'), eventually</div>
         <button onClick={printThis()}>ClickMe</button>
       ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default App;
```

I've read that `this` needs to be binded to the function and I have tried to do so to no avail. Here are the attempts and results of what I've tried:

```
<button onClick={() => printThis()}>ClickMe</button>
```

> undefined

```
<button onClick={this.printThis()}>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printThis')

```
<button onClick={this.printThis}>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printThis')

```
<button onClick={this.printThis.bind(this)}>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printThis')

I noticed that other tutorials have their code wrapped in a class however I don't have that. Is that necessary? If so, how would I implement that into my existing code?

How do I make `this` return the element, rather than an error or 'undefined'?

Comment: You want `onClick={printThis}` and then use the event argument to access the clicked element: `function printThis(event) { const clikcElem = event.target; ...}`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974257/5648954) will provide you with some information as to what to use instead of `this` in different scenarios when using class components. When you're using functional components you'll rarely ever need to use `this`. Class components aren't necessary, you can use react with just functional components (which is what you're using here)

Comment: @NickParsons Using `this` instead of `event.currentTarget` will also work in a `function`. Doesn't matter whether it's a function or class component.

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uxwncL56/)? I've always seen that `this` is unbound when adding it to event handler props like `onClick`, even if it's a `function`, so using `this` will be `undefined`

Comment: Oh, you're right, I didn't expect React to deviate from the DOM standard there

Comment: @Bergi yeah, that particular difference has tripped me up a few times

Comment: The answer from @NickParsons worked! Thanks!