# How do you get the Tag from a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Not the HTML DOM element tag, the JSX tag, the react class name.

Im making an editor and when i add something to the canvas items array i need to check what it is and then call the correct method.

**This is a pseudocode:**

```
changeSelectedItem( nodes ){
        console.log(nodes)
        console.log(nodes[0])
        console.log(nodes[0].nodeName)

        switch(nodes[0] react component name){
            case text:
                selectText
            case image:
                selectimage
            case shape:
                selectShape
        }
```

This is an example of a new component im adding to the items array [image]

In this case i want to get KonvaImage (my custom react class name) from let **new_image** but i don't know how.

Comment: did you check nodes[0].type? React element has type property which indicates type of the element, in case of <h1>fdsd</h1> it would be h1.

Comment: Yeah but .type returns a DOM element type, not the actual class name, i have multiple classes that returns "Shape" but i need the shape type (class name in the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem would be best solved by changing the shape or your state to something like this:

```
[
  {
    type: 'KonvaImage',
    item: <KonvaImage image={image}/>
  },
  {
    type: 'Text',
    item: '....'
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you do this:

```
switch(nodes.type) {
   case 'Text':
     ...
   case 'KonvaImage':
     ...
   etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it's a good idea, but I would love if I can skip this, because it's easy to forget to mantain type and item syncronized and I have to change a lot of code that's already working to adapt it. Upvoted tho

Comment: @ByteVictor - I strongly encourage you to not skip this step. If you're minifying in production, as you will be, you won't actually be able to do what you want anyway. But here's the answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800784/get-component-name-in-react

Comment: I will do it like this then, thanks, im still a newbie with React and it's a bit confusing sometimes. Thanks for your help!