# React components on GitHub Pages become Anonymous

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm working on my pet project on React and deploy it on **gh-pages**.

All worked well before I started using the `name` of the component like `MyComponent.name`. Locally it works well but on deploy crashed. On React Dev Tools I see that all the components become `Anonymous`.

Why it is happened? And how to avoid it?

Comment: Can you put some parts of your code or a project on any online IDE to allow others reproduce your problem?

Comment: Here is the project: https://github.com/polina-prokofieva/NASAinfo, here deployment: https://polina-prokofieva.github.io/NASAinfo

Comment: I think this is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550736/4122078 The name of a component can be accessed in dev environment, but the name will be eliminated because of Webpack's minifying.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! I've got the root of the problem. Components can become Anonymous because of minifying which is different for dev and deploy. So I need to be very careful about using `.name` or not using it at all.